# Turn by turn navigation in app itself

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mkmapview

I was wondering if it is possible to implement the turn by turn navigation in the app itself. 
At the moment I'm using this code.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    //home location
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coords =
    CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.044242,5.621653);
    MKPlacemark *place = [[MKPlacemark alloc]
                          initWithCoordinate:coords addressDictionary:nil];
    MKMapItem *mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc]initWithPlacemark:place];


    //current location
    MKMapItem *mapItem2 = [MKMapItem mapItemForCurrentLocation];


    NSArray *mapItems = @[mapItem, mapItem2];

        NSDictionary *options = @{
        MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving,
        MKLaunchOptionsMapTypeKey:
        [NSNumber numberWithInteger:MKMapTypeStandard],
        MKLaunchOptionsShowsTrafficKey:@YES
    };

    [MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:mapItems launchOptions:options];
}
```

This works great, but it opens the native app application. Is it possible to show this in the app itself without leaving the app?

Kind regards

Comment: what you want exactly ??

Comment: http://bit.ly/Sx7qGT If you go to this link and look at "MKMapItem Options and Enabling Turn-by-Turn Directions". Somewhere half the page. You see what I mean with turn by turn navigation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For show mapview functions within app. use MKMapView instead of using MKMapItem that will redirect you to device`s native application,

For draw route on map view follow bellow links,

1) [MKMapView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html)

2) [Drawing polyines or routes on Mapview](http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=65)

- you can draw path using draw lines on mapview`s overlay you can got brife idea about that in above link and for overlay on **MapView** refer [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlayView_class/Reference/Reference.html).
- As per your question you can draw path turn by turn using that two turning points on map.

You can found all mapView related class references`s official links over [**`here`**.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/_index.html)

Comment: Is this answering if the turn-by-turn directions can be implemented into a standalone app (using MapKit)?

Comment: No, it's not as it's not (currently) possible to have "in app turn by turn with MapKit". You'll need to use another alternative (something in the lines of http://developer.skobbler.com/ )